# Yosemite Single User Mode

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, startup, single-user

Does ***"Single User Mode"*** still work, *post*  ***v10.10.x*** *?*
I tried the following instructions, without success:

---

### OS X Yosemite: Start up in single-user mode

> To troubleshoot your computer’s startup sequence using only UNIX commands, start up in single-user mode. You should do this only if you’re comfortable with UNIX.
>
> Choose  Apple menu > Restart, or press the power button if your Mac is turned off.
>
> Press <kbd>⌘ command</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> as your Mac starts up.
>
> The screen is black with standard white text. You can now run the UNIX commands that you want.
>
> In single-user mode, not all OS X functions are available. To use the standard OS X interface or other high-level aspects of OS X, you need to start up in the standard mode.
>
> To switch back to the standard OS X interface, type reboot, then press <kbd>return ⏎</kbd>.

---

I just get the regular GUI login screen.
Any idea what's causing this (and/or) how to rectify?

Comment: Have you set a [firmware password](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204455) on your Mac?

Comment: @GordonDavisson Quite possibly.

Comment: If you have a firmware password, I don't think there's any way to invoke single-user mode (except removing the firmware password first). You can check by starting with the Option key down, and see if it prompts for the password.